# Using the count method to count bigrams

Tags: python, count

Is it possible to use the count method to count for the occurrence of two objects?

Eg. If I have a list such as

```
list = ['apple', 'red', 'potato', 'apple', 'red']
```

Could I do

```
    word = list[0] + ',' + ' ' + list[1]
    list.count(word)
```

And have it return 2?

I'm aware that python has NTLK, but I am not allowed to use it for the project

Comment: If you're counting things in a sizeable input, it's probably best to use `collections.Counter`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: that won't work because `word` is a string: `"apple, red"`: you'd get 0. your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it yourself by using a dictionary to store all the pairs of words as the keys and how many times they show up as the values. You would need to loop through all the words and concatenate all the pairs and see if they are already in your dictionary. If they are increment that pair by 1 and if they are not in the dictionary add it with a value of one. so for the first pair your dictionary would look like this:

```
{"apple, red":1}
```

at the next time through the loop you would have:

```
{"apple, red":1,
"red, potato":1}
```

and by the time you are finished creating the dictionary you would have:

```
{"apple, red":2,
"red, potato":1,
"potato, apple":1}
```

then you could just look for the pair of words you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can just count on string like that:

```
list = ['apple', 'red', 'potato', 'apple', 'red']
', '.join(list).count(list[0] + ',' + ' ' + list[1])
```

It will simply create a string 'apple, red, potato, apple, red' and on that it will count how many times 'apple, red' is in it.